# IIS7 301 Redirect Using web.config File...(Not Working) in case of Sub Folders and Files

Tags: iis-7, web-config, http-status-code-301

IIS7 301 Redirect Using web.config File...

NOT WORKING....

```
<location path="ProductsAndServices/CustomProfessionalServices.aspx">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="ProductsAndServices/business-video-platform.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

in above location tag i have tried to give a path using ASCII code Like "News/PressReleases/PressReleases.aspx" but still it is not working.

Then I tried to Give File Location it is also not working. as shown below

```
<location path="ULNotifier.zip">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="Support/Resources.aspx?link=Support" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

But When I tried a single page it is working as given below,

```
<location path="Solutions.aspx">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="Solutions/OnlineVideoPlatform.aspx?link=Solutions" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

Can Anybody fix this??